# error TS2416: Property 'originalError' in type 'ApolloError' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'GraphQLError'

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

**Versions**

- apollo-server-errors: 3.2.0
- graphql: 15.6.1/ 15.7.0
- nestjs-cli: 8.1.2
- npm: 6.14.15
- Typescript: 4.4.4

**Error:**

```
node_modules/apollo-server-errors/dist/index.d.ts:10:5 - error TS2416: Property 'originalError' in type 'ApolloError' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'GraphQLError'.
  Type 'Error | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Error | undefined'.
    Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Error | undefined'.

10     originalError: Error | null | undefined;
```

This issue started appearing after I cleared my node_modules by mistake and built using this package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "priojet-backend",
  "version": "0.13.6",
  "description": "The PRIOjet backend providing APIs (GraphQL and REST) and managing the data stored in a Postgres database.",
  "author": "Tobias Wolff, Shivam Pathak",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "type": "commonjs",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production nest build -p tsconfig.build.json",
    "build:docker": "NODE_ENV=docker nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=development nest start",
    "start:dev": "NODE_ENV=development nest start --watch",
    "start:dev:windows": "set NODE_ENV=development && nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "NODE_ENV=development npm-run-all create-api-info-files && NODE_ENV=development nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:debug:docker": "NODE_ENV=docker nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "NODE_ENV=production node dist/main",
    "start:prod:pm2": "NODE_ENV=production pm2 start dist/main.js -i 0",
    "start:devprod": "NODE_ENV=production DEVPROD=1 ts-node ./migrate.ts && node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test TS_JEST=1 jest --detectOpenHandles --maxWorkers=50%",
    "test:vscode-jest": "NODE_ENV=test TS_JEST=1 jest \"--detectOpenHandles\" \"--maxWorkers=50%\"",
    "test:watch": "NODE_ENV=test TS_JEST=1 jest --detectOpenHandles --runInBand --watch --no-cache --silent=false",
    "test:cov": "NODE_ENV=test TS_JEST=1 jest --detectOpenHandles --runInBand --coverage",
    "test:cov:docker": "NODE_ENV=docker TS_JEST=1 jest --detectOpenHandles --coverage",
    "test:debug": "NODE_ENV=test TS_JEST=1 node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "NODE_ENV=test TS_JEST=1 jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json",
    "test:changes": "NODE_ENV=test TS_JEST=1 jest -o",
    "todo": "grep -R --exclude-dir=node_modules 'todo' .",
    "TODO": "grep -R --exclude-dir=node_modules 'TODO' .",
    "loose-types": "echo -e 'anys:\n\n'; grep -r any src; echo -e '\n\nfunctions\n\n'; grep -r function src; echo -e '\n\n';",
    "db": "npx mikro-orm",
    "db:help": "cat ./src/migrations/cli.ts",
    "db:update": "ts-node ./migrate.ts",
    "db:init": "npx mikro-orm schema:create -r",
    "db:migration:create": "npx mikro-orm migration:create",
    "db:migration:up": "npx mikro-orm migration:up       # Migrate up to the latest version",
    "db:migration:down": "npx mikro-orm migration:down     # Migrate one step down",
    "db:migration:list": "npx mikro-orm migration:list     # List all executed migrations",
    "db:migration:pending": "npx mikro-orm migration:pending  # List all pending migrations",
    "prebuild:prod": "rimraf dist # && tsc",
    "create-api-info-files": "./create_api_info_files.sh"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/federation": "^0.33.0",
    "@apollo/gateway": "^0.33.0",
    "@azure/identity": "^1.5.0",
    "@azure/storage-blob": "^12.6.0",
    "@casl/ability": "^5.3.1",
    "@fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs": "^3.2.0",
    "@googlemaps/google-maps-services-js": "^3.2.5",
    "@mikro-orm/cli": "^4.5.9",
    "@mikro-orm/core": "^4.5.9",
    "@mikro-orm/knex": "^4.5.9",
    "@mikro-orm/migrations": "^4.5.9",
    "@mikro-orm/nestjs": "^4.3.0",
    "@mikro-orm/postgresql": "^4.5.9",
    "@mikro-orm/reflection": "^4.5.9",
    "@nestjs/axios": "^0.0.2",
    "@nestjs/common": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^1.0.2",
    "@nestjs/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/event-emitter": "^1.0.0",
    "@nestjs/graphql": "^9.0.6",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^8.0.11",
    "@sentry/node": "^6.13.2",
    "@sentry/tracing": "^6.13.2",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.175",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.32.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.32.0",
    "apollo-server-core": "^3.4.0",
    "apollo-server-errors": "^3.2.0",
    "apollo-server-express": "^3.4.0",
    "apollo-server-types": "^3.3.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "axios-retry": "^3.2.0",
    "azure-storage": "^2.10.4",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "bx24-api": "^1.4.1",
    "check-peer-dependencies": "^4.0.0",
    "class-transformer": "^0.4.0",
    "class-validator": "^0.13.1",
    "cluster": "^0.7.7",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "expo-device": "^3.1.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "form-data": "^4.0.0",
    "graphql": "^15.6.1",
    "graphql-type-json": "^0.3.2",
    "http": "^0.0.1-security",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.1",
    "nest-raven": "^8.0.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-azure-ad": "^4.3.1",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "randomstring": "^1.2.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "request-ip": "^2.1.3",
    "sharp": "^0.29.1",
    "ts-morph": "^12.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.2.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
    "tsutils": "^3.21.0",
    "typescript": "^4.4.2",
    "util": "^0.12.4",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "webpack": "^5.58.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.15",
    "@nestjs/cli": "^8.1.2",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^8.0.3",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^8.0.11",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.2",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.7",
    "@types/node": "^16.10.2",
    "@types/node-fetch": "^3.0.3",
    "@types/request-ip": "0.0.37",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.10",
    "autoclean": "^1.0.2",
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.2",
    "faker": "^5.4.0",
    "jest": "^27.2.4",
    "jest-junit": "^13.0.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "prettier": "2.4.1",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "27.0.5",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.6",
    "ts-node": "^10.3.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "testTimeout": 60000,
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "json",
      "ts",
      "js"
    ],
    "globalSetup": "./jest-setup.ts",
    "globalTeardown": "./jest-teardown.ts",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "reporters": [
      "default",
      "jest-junit"
    ],
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "branches": 40,
        "functions": 45,
        "lines": 75,
        "statements": 75
      }
    },
    "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "dist/package.json",
      "<rootDir>/package.json"
    ]
  },
  "jest-junit": {
    "suiteName": "jest tests",
    "outputDirectory": "test_results",
    "outputName": "junit.xml",
    "uniqueOutputName": "false",
    "classNameTemplate": "{classname}-{title}",
    "titleTemplate": "{classname}-{title}",
    "ancestorSeparator": " › ",
    "usePathForSuiteName": "true"
  },
  "mikro-orm": {
    "useTsNode": true,
    "tsConfigPath": "tsconfig.json",
    "configPaths": [
      "dist/config/database/postgres/mikro-orm.config.js",
      "src/config/database/postgres/mikro-orm.config.ts"
    ],
    "entities": [
      "dist/entities/*.entity.js"
    ],
    "entitiesTs": [
      "src/entities/*.entity.ts"
    ]
  }
}
```

What might be going wrong with my confugration? If it has something to do with the newest updates on apollo-server, when can I expect a solution?  It is a blocker as my application is not runnable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note this was fixed in [graphql.js 15.7.1](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/releases/tag/v15.7.1):

https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/pull/3341

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the type of `GraphQLError.originalError` was changed at some point from `originalError?: Maybe<Error>` to `Error | undefined`. Downgrading to graphql 15.3.0 solved this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to graphql worked for me too. Also, I tried using patch packge as a workaround just not to be blocked.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package

Comment: Downgrading to which version ? Why this link ? Please [edit] your answer to add more details

Comment: Downgrading to 15.3.0. patch-package was just a workaround for solving the problem. It allows you to tweak the code in the dependency creating a dummy package for the node_modules. It is not recommended but I used it for my local trial. Anyway, graphql has resolved the issue in version 15.7.1. I updated it and all works well.